# Java says package doesn't exist. But it's in classpath

Tags: java, json, java-8, package

First of all, Java noob. I'm trying to decode a JSON string. I got the package `json-20160810.jar` and copied it to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_112\lib\ext` but java says it doesn't exist. I tried changing CLASSPATH to the same path as well. I'm not using any IDE

I even tried copying it to `\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\ext` and `\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin`

Comment: Is the error at compile time or run time? How are you running whatever command is failing?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for not using an IDE? A remark: the classpath should include the JAR file, not only its directory.

Comment: Don't put your own JARs into the extensions directory. That's not what it's for.

Comment: If you have both, a JRE and a JDK installed, you have to care which one is used. `javac` is part of the JDK, hence, uses the JRE embedded in the JDK, `\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre`, so the extension folder used by it, is `\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext`. But remember that when you *run* the application, it will use the extension folder of the JRE you use for running it, e.g. `\Java\jre1.8.0_112\lib\ext` or `\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\ext` or whatever JRE you have additionally installed. That’s why the extension folder is not the appropriate folder for such a library (and it will vanish in Java 9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following command:

> javac -classpath ".;home/path/json-20160810.jar" yourJavaFile.java

Comment: I've never seen quotes used with a classpath.

Comment: The quotes aren't needed unless the classpath (or other argument) contains spaces. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: This worked. Thank you
 Is there a way to make java use packages from a certain directory by default rather than specifying the class path every time I run the command?

Comment: @Lord Stiltskin: you can set an environment variable `CLASSPATH`. It will be used whenever no explicit class path is given.